# Why am I suddenly not having push permission?

Tags: git, git-push, permission-denied

I use

```
git remote set-url origin https://ooker777@github.com/QuaCau-TheSphere/LandofSpheres.git
```

But why can't I push?

```
git push
remote: Permission to QuaCau-TheSphere/LandofSpheres.git denied to ooker777.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/QuaCau-TheSphere/LandofSpheres.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am the creator of the organization and the admin of the repo so I must have permission. I pushed successfully before, so it shouldn't be SSH stuff. I don't understand why it happens today.

Comment: 403 can be a rate limit issue... Which usually resolves itself in ae hour or so...

Comment: It has been several days, so it shouldn't be connection issue

Comment: You're using `https://` so Git is not attempting to use ssh. Git is only using https. Is your (presumably cached or stored or keychain-accessed) password on your local computer the/a correct GitHub token for `ooker777`? Does `ooker777`, with that token, have write access to that repository? (Remember that some GitHub tokens have fine-grained permissions. They also can expire very quickly, depending on how you set them up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid opening GitHub Desktop and signing in again, check your credential helper

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

Then, assuming for instance, `manager-core`, check what is registered for your user:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ooker777" | git credential-manager-core get
```

If you don't see anything, register your [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (assuming one which does not expire)

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ooker777\npassword=ghp_yourToken" | git credential-manager-core store
```

That way, you won't have to sign in again.

Comment: Can you explain why the command must be piped like that and not a direct storing command like `git remote set-url ...`? And plus, this is a public repo and I haven't set any permission. I thought that you only need an email to be able to push?

Comment: @Ooker That command is only for storing/getting the credentials needed to push (even to a public repository). The email has nothing to do with remote repository *authentication* but is used for *local* commits *authorship*, local commits that you then push.

Comment: but why not something like `git credential-manager-core store password myToken`? // So even if I don't use github and set my own git server, I (as the upstream) need to have a way to authenticate my downstream, and I (as the downstream) has to prove that I am indeed me?

Comment: @Ooker That command only takes args from stdin, hence the pipe. The credentials is only to be use when pushing to the upstream remote repository. Since said remote is a public one, the downstream repo (the local one) does not need credentials to clone/pull from upstream.

Comment: I open 2 new questions regarding this: [Why doesn't `git credential-manager-core` accept arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74665591/3416774), and [Why does `git config --global credential.helper` show wincred when it seems that I'm using Git Credential Manager Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74665534/3416774). I hope to see you there.// Just to confirm, it is that any git server needs to setup an authentication functionality so that other repos can push to it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was somehow signed out from GitHub. I open GitHub Desktop to sign in and it works again