# Why does `git config --global credential.helper` show wincred when it seems that I'm using Git Credential Manager Core?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

As I understand this article, [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.blog/2020-07-02-git-credential-manager-core-building-a-universal-authentication-experience/) is not the same with [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) or [Windows Credentials](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0). After using this command
`printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ooker777\npassword=ghp_yourToken" | git credential-manager-core store`
I'm able to push. Checking Windows Credentials I only see my GitHub password is stored in there, which will not work because GitHub requires it to be token. So it's clear that I'm not using wincred.

Yet `git config --global credential.helper` still shows that I'm using wincred. Why is that?

Comment: Upgrading Git will not, in general, touch your own configuration in any way. Git configurations are so flexible and so personal that this would be a minefield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wincred` was the legacy [credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) on Windows.

It has been replaced by [GCM](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (Git Credential Manager), and [after Git 2.38.1, is called `manager` (no longer "`manager-core`")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309)

If you have upgraded [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you can safely change your credential helper to manager.

```bash
# up to Git 2.38.1 on Windows
git config --global credential.helper manager-core

# Git 2.39+
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Comment: so should the new GCM be considered as an upgraded version of the old GCM, or a totally different, unrelated one?

Comment: and why is it that `git config --global credential.helper` still shows `wincred`

Comment: @Ooker the new GCM is cross-platform and replaces a bunch of legacy system-specific credentials helpers (including wincred). Your current helper shows wincred because you might have started with an old Git for Windows (type `git --version` to confirm).

Comment: so I understand that the new GCM is a totally, different program to the old GCM, which happens to make the old one obsolete.// My version was indeed old (2.33.0.windows.2), but as it was clear that wincred wasn't used, I don't understand why it didn't reflect that. What's more is that I have upgrade it to 2.38.1, yet it still shows wincred

Comment: @Ooker When you upgrade, it does not set the credential helper if it was previously set. You can go ahead and safely change it now