# Why doesn't `git credential-manager-core` accept arguments?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

In the question [Why am I suddenly not having push permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74593188/3416774) I was advised to use this command to store my credential:

`printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ooker777\npassword=ghp_yourToken" | git credential-manager-core store`

I was explained that the command doesn't accept arguments, so it must be piped like that. Why is it so? Why not something like this?

```
git credential-manager-core store password myToken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal interface for storing and retrieving credentials from system-specific helpers described by "[`git credential`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential)" refers to [`credential.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/805265fcf7a737664a8321aaf4a0587b78435184/credential.h).

The design presented in that file confirms the use of pipes to get arguments:

```
+-----------------------+
| Git code (C)          |--- to server requiring --->
|                       |        authentication
|.......................|
| C credential API      |--- prompt ---> User
+-----------------------+
^      |
| pipe |
|      v
+-----------------------+
| Git credential helper |
+-----------------------+
```

> The Git code (typically a remote-helper) will call the C API to obtain credential data like a login/password pair (`credential_fill`).
> The API will itself call a remote helper (e.g. "`git credential-cache`" or "`git credential-store`") that may retrieve credential data from a
> store.
> If the credential helper cannot find the information, the C API will prompt the user. Then, the caller of the API takes care of
> contacting the server, and does the actual authentication.